# Percentage matching of queries in sharepoint 2010 search

Tags: search

I was just wondering if it's possible to make sharepoint search results show entries very similar to the query entered. I just realised this when i came across this possibility when i ran a search for 'Jon' instead of 'John' by mistake. I realised it could have far reaching impact on our business. Do help me out with your thoughts. Stemming is already active so I'm looking for something different, for mostly names or spelling mistakes.Thanks!!

Comment: Are you thinking about this for content besides people search?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 offers phonetic people search. According to a technet article [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee667266.aspx) :

***Phonetic name matching and nickname matching**
Users can search for a person in the organization by name without knowing the exact spelling of the name. For example, the search query "John Steal" could yield "John Steele" in the search results; results for the search query "Jeff" include names that contain "Geoff." In addition, nickname matching makes it possible for a search query for "Bill" to yield results that include "William."*

Also for more information, you can check out the blog posts [here](http://www.kowalski.ms/2010/07/09/sharepoint-server-2010-phonetic-and-nickname-search/) and [here](http://dotnet.sys-con.com/node/1317530)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [thesaurus](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/enterprisesearch/archive/2008/09/23/how-to-customize-the-thesaurus-in-sharepoint-search-and-search-server.aspx) for this.  But you will have to manually manage it.  It works by expanding your search, so if you searched for "Jon", you could make it search "Jon", "John", "Johnny", "Jonathan" etc...

Adding everyone's nicknames to the thesaurus could be difficult and time consuming so I'm hoping there's a better solution around :)